# Iteration over the output

Tags: python

I want to get the value of accessKey from the below output from access_key in python.
Please tell me how can I iterate over it and get the value of `accessKey = ABCDEFGHIJ`.

```
access_key = [SIM_IdentityOption(
identity=SIM_Identity(displayName='system-3b07c9ab-e049-42cf-b447-d1895c799dcd',
                      creationTime=1478611077.671846,
                      identityType=0,
                      enabled=True,
                      canonicalId='805821d085f1de0860dccdd5c8',
                      modificationTime=1478611077.734763,
                      apiKeys=[SIM_ApiKey(secretKey=None, creationTime=1478611077.73346, accessKey='ABCDEFGHIJ', enabled=True)],
                      email='system@internal.amplidata.com',
                      parentAccountCanonicalId=None))
          ]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? Does it work?

Comment: Why do you want to iterate? Why did you put a single item into a list in the first place?

Comment: This is the command output which I cannot change. I am not creating it

Comment: Do you get this output as a string?

Comment: `apiKeys[0].accessKey`?

Comment: No, I don't get the output as a string

Comment: If this is your written python code, then why dont you just use the value `ABCDEFGHIJ`? It is stated as an input, isn't it?

Comment: Its not an input, its a output of some command which i cannot change

Answer (score 0):

This works-

```
access_key[0].identity.apiKeys[0].accessKey
```

Answer (score 0):

```
output = """[SIM_IdentityOption(
identity=SIM_Identity(displayName='system-3b07c9ab-e049-42cf-b447-d1895c799dcd',
                      creationTime=1478611077.671846,
                      identityType=0,
                      enabled=True,
                      canonicalId='805821d085f1de0860dccdd5c8',
                      modificationTime=1478611077.734763,
                      apiKeys=[SIM_ApiKey(secretKey=None, creationTime=1478611077.73346, accessKey='ABCDEFGHIJ', enabled=True)],
                      email='system@internal.amplidata.com',
                      parentAccountCanonicalId=None))
          ]"""

code = 'accessKey=\''
startcode = output.find(code) + len('accessKey=\'')
endcode = output.find('\'', startcode+1)
accesskey = output[startcode:endcode]
print accesskey
```